# Is it possible to add XSLT template to two different nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my template to format the date.

```
<xsl:template match="data/header/ORDER_DATE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 7, 2)" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(., 5, 2)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3 * ($month - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is the code for applying the template to my header.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ORDER_DATE" />
```

Below is the code for corresponding xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <header>
        <ORDER_DATE>20161209</ORDER_DATE>
    </header>
    <order_item>
       <ITEM_DATE>20161211000000</ITEM_DATE>
    </order_item>
    <order_item>
        <ITEM_DATE>20161212000000</ITEM_DATE>
    </order_item>
</data>
```

But, there are two different nodes where I need to apply the same template. Is there any way to make this template as a common function so, that I can apply it anywhere with reusability?

Comment: What does your XML look like? Just to provide a full [mcve]?

Comment: Providing a desired output could be helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="ORDER_DATE|ITEM_DATE">
...
```

Or, if you want it even more general, try using a named template

```
<xsl:template match="data/*/*[contains(local-name(),'DATE')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="date" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="date">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 7, 2)" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(., 5, 2)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3 * ($month - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```